# Instanciar Unit of Work com apenas 1 contexto. EF 6 Simple Injector

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ioc

Em uma aplicação simples, tenho o código abaixo que funciona até determinado ponto, muito bem. Porém, para cada Serviço que é instanciado para o Form, uma nova unidade de trabalho é criada, consequentemente um novo Contexto. 
Com isso, enquanto o usuário estiver trabalhando no form, ele não vê outras atualizações que outros usuários fizeram em outras instâncias. Mesmo atualizando as listas.

Já testei fazer um Refresh/Reaload no momento de obter os dados, porém, ele só atualiza com os dados do banco na entidade principal, e não das lista contidas nessa entidade.
Também já testei usar o contexto ou a unidade de trabalho como Singleton, porém, além de não resolver o problema, no meu ponto de vista é uma péssima prática.

Do jeito que está, quando atualizo a entidade Lista ele gera o erro:

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Pelo que entendi quando o Form é instanciado, ele cria 2 instâncias da unidade de trabalho, 1 para cada serviço.

Entendo também que ele deveria criar uma unidade de trabalho, com seu contexto, e usá-la para todos os serviços instanciados para o Form. Assim como realizar o Dispose desses serviços ao sair dele (O que não ocorre).

Alguém já passou pela implementação de algo com esses conceitos e dar uma luz?

**program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Container container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new LifetimeScopeLifestyle();

    container.Register(typeof(IServiceBase<>), typeof(ServiceBase<>));
    container.Register<IVisaoService, VisaoService>();
    container.Register<IListaService, ListaService>();
    container.Register<ITipoListaService, TipoListaService>();
    container.Register<IProcedimentoService, ProcecdimentoService>();

    container.Register(typeof(IRepositoryBase<>), typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
    container.Register<IVisaoRepository, VisaoRepository>();
    container.Register<IListaRepository, ListaRepository>();
    container.Register<ITipoListaRepository, TipoListaRepository>();
    container.Register<IProcedimentoRepository, ProcedimentoRepository>();

    container.Register<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();


    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(Global._container.GetInstance<Principal>());
}
```

**Form**

```
private IVisaoService _visaoService;
private IListaService _listaService;

public Form(IVisaoService visaoService, IListaService listaService)
{
    _visaoService = visaoService;
    _listaService = listaService;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void CarregaDados()
{
    List<Visao> visoes = _visaoService.ObtemTodos().OrderByDescending(c => c.Numero_Visao).ToList();

    //Carrega os dados
}


private void Renomear()
{
    lista.Descrisao = txtDescicao.Text;
    _listaService.Atualizar(lista);
}
```

**Serviço**

```
public class ListaService : ServiceBase<Lista>, IListaService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public ListaService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        : base(uow, uow.ListaRepository)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }
}
```

**Repositório**

```
public class ListaRepository : RepositoryBase<Lista>, IListaRepository
{
    private readonly Contexto Db;

    public ListaRepository(Contexto db) : base(db)
    {
        Db = db;
    }
}
```

**Unidade de trabalho**

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private bool _disposed;

    private Contexto _db;

    private IVisaoRepository _visaoRepository;
    private IListaRepository _listaRepository;

    public UnitOfWork(Contexto db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public IVisaoRepository VisaoRepository
    {
        get { return _visaoRepository = _visaoRepository ?? new VisaoRepository(_db); }
    }

    public IListaRepository ListaRepository
    {
        get { return _listaRepository = _listaRepository ?? new ListaRepository(_db); }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _db.Dispose();
            }
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que você está implementando o pattern `unit of work` se o EF já usa este padrão nativamente? Outra coisa: usar singleton é uma péssima prática, mas usar o contexto sem dar `Dispose()` é uma boa ideia? Acho que você precisa rever alguns conceitos...

Comment: @jbueno, peguei o bonde andando. Como o EF usa isso? Entendo que o uow encapsula os respositórios justamente para reutilizá-los. Quanto ao Dispose, também não acho uma boa prática, quis dizer que, como o código está, ele não faz, e é isso que acho errado. Nesse cenário achei que o IoC seria o responsável por instanciar o que precisa e fazer o Dispose depois de usado, mas pelo que andei lendo o IoC não faz isso. Vlw

Comment: Vamos do começo, por que você decidiu fazer isto dessa forma? Por que não decidiu usar apenas o EF?

Comment: Não fui eu q decidi, pediram justamente pra eu acertar esse problema das atualizações dos dados nas telas. Iniciei tentando resolver com o Refresh/Reload, mas não resolve

Comment: Consegui a autorização pra mudar tudo. Vou fazer do jeito que eu sei. Acho que tem que estar muito confortável para usar todos esses conceitos, e o projeto tem que valer a pena. Vlw @jbueno. Só não sei se deixo a pergunta ai ou se excluo.